# Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to parse MongoDB URI:

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter-3

its connect to mongodb localhost but not connect to mongodb atlas using URI
Unable to connect to MongoDB: Failed to parse MongoDB URI: 'mongodb://mongodb+srv://cluster0.mdoxuh6.mongodb.net/:27017/MyFirstProject'. Invalid host string in URI.

give me ci3 to mongodb atlas fetch

Comment: Change `mongodb://mongodb+srv://cluster0.mdoxuh6.mongodb.net/:27017/MyFirstProject` to just `mongodb+srv://cluster0.mdoxuh6.mongodb.net/:27017/MyFirstProject` and then try.

Comment: mongodb+srv://cluster0.mdoxuh6.mongodb.net/:27017/MyFirstProject

i added this but error showing like this 'mongodb://mongodb+srv://cluster0.mdoxuh6.mongodb.net/:27017/MyFirstProject'. Invalid host string in URI.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you entered as your URI:

```
 'mongodb://mongodb+srv://cluster0.mdoxuh6.mongodb.net/:27017/MyFirstProject'
```

perhaps it need to be correct to following:

```
 'mongodb+srv://cluster0.mdoxuh6.mongodb.net:27017/MyFirstProject'
```